# Extract characters from string using SQL

Tags: sql, substring, character, tableau-api, charindex

I have a column of ID's and I am needing to use SQL to extract the first two characters after the " - "

I am using the Custom SQL Query in Tableau 10.4

Example Column:

```
ABC - BCA - IT
AD - HD - A
QWE - QWE - E
```

What I need:

```
BC
HD
QW
```

I have tried to use the substring and Charindex function, but cannot seem to get it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
select substring(example, charindex(' - ', example) + 3, 2)
from (values ('ABC - BCA - IT'), ('AD - HD - A')) v(example)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with SQL Server, then you can use `substring()` function :

```
select substring(col, charindex('-', col) + 1, 2)) as need
```

Comment: Do you know if I am using the custom SQL query function in Tableau if the substring / charindex functions are supported?

Answer (score 1):

With **MySQL**, there are a lot of possible expressions. The big difference is  handling of string values that don't contain exactly two dash characters.

MySQL provides a handy `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Assuming the string values contain exactly two dash characters, then something like this:

```
 SELECT c.foo
      , TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(c.foo,'-',2),'-',-1)) AS mid
   FROM ( 
          SELECT  'ABC - BCA - IT' AS foo
          UNION ALL SELECT 'AD - HD - A'
          UNION ALL SELECT 'QWE - QWE - E'
        ) c
```

Omit the `TRIM` function if we don't want to remove the leading and trailing spaces.

```
foo              mid
---------------  ---
ABC - BCA - IT   BCA
AD - HD - A      HD
QWE - QWE - E    QWE
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've worked with Tableau, but IIRC this would be something this should work:

```
LEFT(TRIM(SPLIT([Column], `-`, 2)), 2)
```

To the best of my knowledge, no version of Tableau supports `substring`.

Alternatively, this *might* also help:

```
MID([Column], FIND([Column], "-") + 2, 2)
```